# Extract the elements of list if they are present in the column in python dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['the cat, dog is blue', 'the sky is green', 'the dog is black']})

frame
              a
0   the cat,dog is blue
1  the sky is green
2  the dog is black

mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']
```

Expected output

```
              a                   matched_str
   0   the cat, dog is blue        cat, dog
   1  the sky is green             NA
   2  the dog is black             dog
```

Please advise

Tried as below:

```
import re
def pattern_searcher(search_str:str, search_list:str):
    search_obj = re.search(search_list, search_str)
    if search_obj :
        return_str = search_str[search_obj.start(): search_obj.end()]
    else:
        return_str = 'NA'
    return return_str

pattern = '|'.join(mylist)

frame['matched_str'] = frame['a'].apply(lambda x: pattern_searcher(search_str=x, search_list=pattern))
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: import re
def pattern_searcher(search_str:str, search_list:str):

    search_obj = re.search(search_list, search_str)
    if search_obj :
        return_str = search_str[search_obj.start(): search_obj.end()]
    else:
        return_str = 'NA'
    return return_str

Comment: frame['matched_str'] = frame['a'].apply(lambda x: pattern_searcher(search_str=x, search_list=pattern))

Comment: Please update your question with what you have attempt so it's easier to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `str.extractall` after creating a bitwise OR `|` string of your values.

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['the cat, dog is blue', 'the sky is green', 'the dog is black']})

mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']

words =  '|'.join(mylist)
#'dog|cat|fish'

frame['b'] = frame['a'].str.extractall(f"({words})").groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)

                      a        b
0  the cat, dog is blue  cat,dog
1      the sky is green      NaN
2      the dog is black      dog
```